# K-means clustering on point cloud data

Tags: c++, k-means, point-cloud-library

I am trying to implement K-means clustering algorithm on a point cloud. I am not sure, however, how to import the data as input for the k-means member of pcl. The documentation has proven to be a little confusing. 
So far I have imported the pcd into a point cloud and transferred it into a vector but I dont know how to proceed from here and initialize Kmeans directly.

```
int main (int argc, char** argv)
{ 
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud_in(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);

    std::vector<pcl::PointXYZ> cloud;
    pcl::io::loadPCDFile ("Scene02 - Cloud.pcd", *cloud_in);

    for (int i = 0; i < cloud_in->size(); i++)
    {
        cloud[i] = cloud_in->points[i];
    }

    pcl::Kmeans real(300000, 3); 
    real.setInputData(cloud);



 }
```

I realize that the syntax is wrong but I am not sure what the right one is either.

Comment: If you want others to post code/ help you specifically.  Please demonstrate your work so far by showing your current code and stating what you have tried that didn't work.

Comment: This was far more confusing than I thought it was going to be. (I have a fair bit of experience with pcl and this function is written poorly imo)  Thank you for this question, as I think others will find it useful!

Comment: Indeed! On the surface this functions seems to take all the complexity of implementing a kmeans algorithm in PCL but executing it without proper tutorial is exhausting. I hope it helps others in the future!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function is very odd as compared to how pcl generally does things (centering around custom point types).  Basically, the oddity is that you have to enter points via a specified dimension vector rather than a custom point type.  Here is tested and functional sample code: (obviously you need to provide your own file name, and you will likely want to adjust cluster size)

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    std::string filePath = "../PointCloudFiles/beaconJR.pcd";
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr tempCloud(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
    if (pcl::io::loadPCDFile(filePath, *tempCloud) == -1) //* load the file
    {printf("failed file load!\n");}
    else
    {
        pcl::Kmeans real(static_cast<int> (tempCloud->points.size()), 3);
        real.setClusterSize(3); //it is important that you set this term appropriately for your application
        for (size_t i = 0; i < tempCloud->points.size(); i++)
        {
            std::vector<float> data(3);
            data[0] = tempCloud->points[i].x;
            data[1] = tempCloud->points[i].y;
            data[2] = tempCloud->points[i].z;
            real.addDataPoint(data);
        }

        real.kMeans();
        // get the cluster centroids 
        pcl::Kmeans::Centroids centroids = real.get_centroids();
        std::cout << "points in total Cloud : " << tempCloud->points.size() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "centroid count: " << centroids.size() << std::endl;
        for (int i = 0; i<centroids.size(); i++)
        {
            std::cout << i << "_cent output: x: " << centroids[i][0] << " ,";
            std::cout << "y: " << centroids[i][1] << " ,";
            std::cout << "z: " << centroids[i][2] << std::endl;
        }
    }

    std::cin.get();
    std::cin.get();
}
```

Cheers!

--edit

As far as visualizing the clusters.  I think (untested) that "pcl::Kmeans::PointsToClusters" is going to give you a vector with custer labels per point which you can use to index through the original cloud and separate them.

Comment: I have seen this tutorial as well but the one that I am trying to use is the Kmeans filter itself as mentioned in PCL. 
http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/classpcl_1_1_kmeans.html#a8788bd4098ea370e018119fc516a5eb4

In this case as you can see I can directly initiate Kmeans like a filter but how to innitialize it and how to set the input if not mentioned. 

Also, from point cloud to a vector of points is easy but it is only a float vector is allowed as input in Kmeans. Hence the confusion.

Comment: I am so confused now.  Did this answer your question...?  Do you have your code working? (*i did not downvote you ftr, I just commented that to tell you why people will likely downvote this question)

Comment: I donot have a code working. And unfortunately there is no tutorial on how to use kmeans directly in pcl. So far I have managed to input data in a point cloud and transfer it into a PointXYZ vector. But how to initialize kmeans is where I am confused.

Comment: I am aware of that, as I would have posted a link to that if there was one.  But the point of SO is to help you get there, not give an answer.  If you post what code you have/ what you have tried, we can help get your code working.

Comment: Then the hope is that if people are trying to do kmeans clustering in the future they may stumble across this post and will find the resulting working example code

Comment: Thank you for not downvoting! This is a problem I have been trying to get across the entire day. Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Ya... SO has some pretty nasty first question policies that I honestly find kinda off-putting to newcomers.  Anyhow, gotta keep comments to business.  If you post what code you have, I will try it on my pcl setup and see what I can do to help out.

Comment: Thanks! I have added the code. Try it on your setup and let me know if I am anywhere near the right direction.

Comment: the instance "real" is not taking in the input data from a PointXYZ vector in the first place, let alone set clustersize. It only wants Kmeans Point type vector which is completely uncharted territory for me. This is what I meant by lack of tutorials and appropriate documentation.

Comment: Ok, I will look into that then.

Comment: Thanks! Because when I change the vector type from PointXYZ to Kmeans::Point,I cannot use  = to copy all the data from pointcloud to vector.

Comment: In the future, never accept an answer until your question has been solved.  Remember that the voting and points is secondary in SO, the primary goal is to have well worded questions with clear concise answers that others will be able to easily find in the future if they run into a similar problem.  If you prematurely accept an answer, those who can help may not find it and those who need help will just be left with an unsolved question as you were.  Good luck on your project!

Comment: I didn't accept your answer because of points. I did it because you were trying to help. Like you said SO can be a bit harsh and confusing for a newcomer. Thank you again for the help!

Comment: Apologies for the undoing of acceptance but I didnt want to give the appearance that it is working. The static_cast<int> used in initialization of "real" is not acceptable as an argument for the constructor instance. Once I removed it, the project built perfectly well. 

However, when I used my point cloud, most of my centroids were "-inf". I dont know if it is because the function is poorly written but that doesnt seem right. Would like to get your opinion if I should abandon this function and try a different algorithm.

Comment: is there anyway I can access the various clusters? I want to visualize them separately.

Comment: Lets fix the first problem first.  Did you remove nan and inf from your cloud?  Also, I do not understand why static cast did not work for you, this runs on my computer and generates true centroids

Comment: Yes! Removed NaN using filters.h and pcl_nan and pcl_isinf check. But the static_cast thing is a total unknown for me.

Comment: Are you getting valid centroids now?

Comment: Nope. Vector subscript out of range.

Comment: On which vector?  ...I think we are getting off topic for this question

Comment: I tried to move all the finite points from a temp cloud to a new cloud, and I missed up the vector range somehow. 
`for (int i = 0; i < tempCloud->points.size(); i++)
  {
   if (pcl_isfinite(tempCloud->points[i].x) && pcl_isfinite(tempCloud->points[i].y) && pcl_isfinite(tempCloud->points[i].z))
   {
    int j = 0;
    cloud->points[j] = tempCloud->points[i];
    j++;
   }`

Comment: I think this question is adequately answered and if you have additional problems about c++ or otherwise you should put them in another question after searching the site for answers.